# Return value of std::hash ofr (x86/x64)

Tags: c++, std

I use std::hash for unordered datastructure and save these in ROM. I have to correct use it on x86 and x64 OS. 
Does it possibly to get equal values for std::hash on x86/x64 os versions?

Comment: What is "ofr" please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The hash value is not designed to be communicated or stored outside one run of the program.

There is nothing in the standard to prevent it producing a different value on a subsequent run, and certainly no guarantee that it will have the same value on another architecture.